# DataGrid SelectedItem Binding

Tags: wpf, binding, mvvm, datagrid, selecteditem

Below is the code behind in my view model:

```
private DataRow selectedErrorRow;
public DataRow SelectedErrorRow
{
    get { return selectedErrorRow; }
    set { selectedErrorRow = value; base.RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedErrorRow"); }
}
```

Then this in my view:

```
<DataGrid SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedErrorRow,Mode=TwoWay}"
```

The binding somewhat works... It "gets" the value when the datagrid is drawn but it never sets it when a new value is selected/highlighted.... Any ideas?

**Note the item source for the datagrid is a DataTable.**

**EDIT:**
The Datagrid is in a PopUp, when the datagrid gets drawn it will get the binded value (null). However once I selected/highlight a row it will NOT 'set' anything. It will however 'set' the binded value null when its redrawn (the popup is open, i selected a row, close it,and reopen it). The thing is It never sets the value to anything but null, and it only sets it during the secound time its drawn.

Comment: Could you show the line of Code/XAML which sets ItemsSource of your Grid?

Comment: ItemsSource="{Binding DataRowsWithErrors}" DataRowsWithErrors is a DataTable

Comment: Looks like a DataContext issue. DataRowsWithErrors belongs to your DataContext (it's an MV property likely) do you have SelectedErrorRow located at the same logical level?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what your asking. But both DataRowsWithErrors and selectedErrorRow are located in the same ViewModel. I don't think its a DataContext issue?

Comment: put a breakpoint inside your DP Value Changed event handler for your grid and see if your its SelectedItem ever gets changed.

Comment: Hi Dmitry, I edited my question to add more information. The breakpoint is only hit during the 2nd time around (drawn for the 2nd time) and its value is set to null. It never gets set when i select a row. I'm starting to think I can't bind to selectedItem if my DataSource is a DataTable.

Comment: do you force 'FullRow' selection? If so, try setting these for your DataGrid: SelectionMode="Single" & SelectionUnit="FullRow", at least it makes sense now why it doesn't update your VM - null==null (as far as c# is concerned), so no VM update happens. You are not using 'as' anywhere are you - as casting to the wring type will result in null.

Comment: have you tried adding UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" into your xaml?

Comment: I tried both suggestions above, both did not work. I did however notice that when i click a cell on the new/add row (bottom of the datagrid) it will set the selecteditem to null also. However I'm still unable to have it set the selectedItem to the highlighted row

Comment: i think it would be worth trying a different datasource type. ive never actually bound to a datatable, i use dataviews instead

Comment: I did it... Looks Like the problem only happens when binding to a DataTable

Comment: Are you sure that the itemssource for your datagrid is collection of "DataRow" objects..? if possible please publish the itemsource you are providing for datagrid

Comment: Hi Bathineni, I'm not sure what it is exactly. The ItemsSource is of type DataTable. As far as I know The rows come from the DataTable's DataRowCollection which is made up of DataRows.

Comment: Sweet, Bathineni led me to the right answer. DataTable is a collection of DataRowViews? If I have my binding as DataRowView it works. The problem is solved thank you all!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I needed to change what I was binding to. It needs to bind to a `DataRowView` and not a `DataRow`.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue previously and figured it out myself.

It is not intuitive to know what is the issue since you cannot see the real value in debug but when you data bind a `DataTable` on a datagrid at first you think it has a `DataTable` type as source right ? Well you are wrong if you think that.

Actually the datagrid or the binding (i still don't know where it happen as i only see `DataTable` on my side) does a cast/convert of `DataTable` object like `DataTable.AsDataView()` to convert it to a `DataView` by itself so the selected item make sense to me to be `DataRowView`.

I know it's old question but this might shed light to those who get here and also look to set value as data source especially converters

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
DataGrid SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedErrorRow,Mode=TwoWay}
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth maybe but if tomorrow microsoft change the default this piece of code still works.

Comment: @Franck: (1) That won't happen (2) that wasn't the question (3) it doesn't help the OP